# Camera memory card full but cannot read or download files

Tags: sd-card

I've got a CanonSDC-32M card that reads full in my camera but I can only view a dozen or so pictures.Tried it in my laptop and the same result.How could I go about downloading my files or recovering them if need be?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there are so few pictures on that card is because according to what I've read about it online, it's only 32 megabytes. By today's standards that's really tiny. A reasonable size for today would be 8GB.

They aren't very expensive, unless you need a really fast one (for recording videos). If taking pictures is the only thing you want to do, you should be ok with a class 3 one (the higher the class, the faster and more expensive they are.)

I'm not sure what you mean by asking how you should download your files. You should be able to simply select them and copy or move them to a desired location on your computer. Some vendors provide additional software to make the process more comfortable, but it's generally not needed.

The only thing preventing you from downloading the files from your card is if it's locked. There should be a small slider on the side of it. Make sure it's in the unlocked position (sometimes the slider goes down into the "lock" position on its own as the card is inserted into the reader. To prevent that from happening, if you are experiencing this problem, simply block the slider with, for example, a piece of paper.)